# fetching data from URL in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsurl

I am making iPad application, in which, I am fetching data from a URL. Sometimes, I retrieved `Null` instead.

In my URL i am passing my id dynamically, for eg: in this code i passed `id = PNB`, 
 here is the code snippet:

```
     NSMutableString*str;

     NSString *urlAddress = @”http://ipad.idealake.com/stockquote.aspx?id=PNB”;
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

str=[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]; //(here compiler shows me warning initWithContentsOfURL is deprected)

          NSLog(@"str=%@",str);
```

When I do NSLog of str, it shows me null value,

> ```
> output: str=null
> ```

However, when I pass `id=SUNPHARMA` or `id=AMBUJA` it shows me proper output but when i pass `id=TCS` or `id=LT` it again shows me  null value in my `str`. What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to trim your `id` , and try...

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting `nil` is probably because the `id` argument is sometimes wrong (`TCS` or `LT`). Double check them, the URL probably hasn't any information to give in response.

About the warning, as stated in the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html), the `initWithContentsOfURL:` method is deprecated since iOS 2.0, you are encouraged to use `initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` instead.

Comment: dude you rock.. can you write syntex for the same ?

Comment: this should look like : `str=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];` assuming you use utf-8

Answer (score 0):

PLease use ASIHTTPRequest LIB to solve all your problem. They do download data to memory or directly to a file on disk, cache responses and download progress indicators for operation queues.  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/